# Heroku - Cannot log in without authenticator

Tags: heroku

I haven’t logged in to my heroku account over the last 3 to 5 years.

When I tried today, my password did work so I used the “forgot your password” link.  When I reset the password and tried to log in I was asked to verify my account with an Authenticator code - which I never had.
[image]

How do I log in?

Comment: "which I never had"—I suspect you are wrong about this, and the whole point of MFA is to prevent logging in without the authenticator. Contact Heroku support. [We can't help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service request and [such topics are off-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).